# tab order on form when date is selected using the date date picker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

On Forms when I use the date picker on a date field to select the date and then tab out of the date the focus automatically moves to the address bar when in Chrome- On IE it moves focus to the first field.  Is there a way around this behavior?We want to be able to tab through the form while keeping logical focus. I am using JQuery 3.1.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: I tried with following code and its giving the alert box but focus is not setting

$(document).ready(function () {
      $("body").on("change dp.change", "#dateOfBirth", function(event){
        alert('hello');
        document.getElementById("dateOfBirth").focus(); // also tried $(this).focus();
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that the datepicker is rendered out of order from the rest of the form.

[Use this javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_tabindex.asp) to find out the tabindex of the datepicker and the fields surrounding your datepicker.

From there you should be able to set the tabindex in plain HTML (ex: `tabindex="2"`) to whatever you want.

I think that if you set the tabindex to match the date field or maybe the value after the date field, that it'll tab properly.